# Best way to store application navigation for Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So my application re-uses quite a few activities. Originally I was simply adding a "fromClass" line as an extra to Intents as I switched between activities. The problem now is that I need to know which class I started with several activities ago, in order to display information properly on the current activity. I was trying to use an arraylist of strings to store the order and remove them from the list as I went backwards, but I cannot get strings to translate into class names and work correctly.

At the start of the activity I'm adding the following way:

```
Global.appNavigation.add("SecondActivity.class")
```

When I call onBackPressed() I'm doing this:

```
/* Remove Last Object (this class) */
    Globals.appNavigation
            .remove(Globals.appNavigation.size() - 1);
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(Globals.applicationNavigation
                .get(Globals.appNavigation.size() - 1));
        Activity obj = (Activity) c.newInstance();
        Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, c);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Back", "Could not get a class name");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm constantly getting the ClassNotFoundException. Is there a better way to do this? This application I'm working with is getting quite large, so not calling finish() to an activity may not work in this case.

Comment: Why would the application being large prevent you from simply finish()ing the current activity to move back up the back-stack?

Comment: I was worried about memory constraints when moving between activities if I didn't call a "finish()"

Comment: Android handles it for you.  If the previous activity was destroyed by the system, it will be re-created with its starting intent.  Any additional state should be put away in onSaveInstanceState and can be retrieved through the bundle provided in onCreate to restore the full UI state.  Generally, Android will work pretty sure to make sure this doesn't happen with the active application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling the "finish()" method, but did a better job keeping track of data that needed to be persistent.

Thanks to Ben Von Handorf for the suggestion (see comments 1 and 3 on original question)